# SwiftUI Accessibility Custom Tab View

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I am trying to figure out the best way for voiceover users to navigate directly to the custom tab bar I've created. It's not a standard Apple TabView, but looks and acts like it. My thought was to give the tab bar it's own accessibilityFocusState identifier and create a rotor entry, but it seems that this is impossible as that's not what the Rotor was designed for.

Currently a user must navigate through the entire view in order to get back down to the tab bar at the bottom of the screen. That seems cumbersome if they wanted to jump directly to the tab bar (maybe they selected a tab and looked at one thing in the view and then wanted a different tab?).

Just wondering what others are doing in this situation to assist those users who require voiceover and accessibility?

A really simplistic idea of what I'm talking about would be:

```
extension MyView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        enum AccessFocusFields {
            case mainContent
            case tabBar
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @AccessbilityFocusState var accessFocus: MyView.ViewModel.AccessFocusFields?

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("My Text")
            Button("Button 1") { }
            Text("My Next Text")
            Button("Button 2") { }
            Text("My Next Text")
            Button("Button 3") { }
        }
        .accessibilityFocused($accessFocus, equals: .mainContent)
        // THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE OF WHAT I THOUGHT WOULD BE A GOOD SOLUTION
        // BUT OBVIOUSLY IS INVALID CODE
        .accessibilityRotor("Tab Bar") {
            accessFocus = .tabBar
        }

        TabBar()
        .accessibilityFocused($accessFocus, equals: .tabBar)
    }
}
```

Obviously there's a lot more to the code than this, but it gives an example where if I could create a custom rotor, or some way other than a button to allow voiceover users to navigate directly to the tab bar, or to the view that would be very helpful as there are generally a lot of elements in the view itself and navigating through all of them just to get back to the tab bar would take some time.

Also, it doesn't have to be a rotor. I am really looking for opinions on the best solution to implement for my voiceover users. If there's anything I can do to help them, I want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

A tab bar for navigation is considered secondary to the content on the screen. Users of assistive technology understand how to move through a View and expect to move through it as they normally would. They would not expect to try and find a way to jump to the tab navigation using a rotor. Dont try and complicate things for users or change the expected behavior of a View as that is more confusing to a user.